# What does the words "strafe your shot" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In a game's description, I found the following sentence:

"Even if you initially miss, you can keep the player moving to strafe your shot and still hit a few targets."

I know the lexical meaning of the word "strafe", but I am not sure if the phrase "strafe your shot" does not have a distinct gaming connotation.

Comment: If this is really about gaming slang, it should be on arqade.SE: but actually it seems clear that it is just a gamer stretching a metaphor too far.

Comment: It's not possible to strafe a single shot. (So that would be a mistake in usage.) Nor does *strafing your shots* mean anything different than *strafing*. It's actually somewhat redundant. But if you know what *strafing* means, then you should understand the general intention of the sentence. (And if you think there *is* a specific gaming connotation, then it's off topic for this site.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems specific to gaming terminology.

Answer (score 1):

**Strafing** in video games is moving sideways or backwards while still looking forward (instead of looking the direction you're moving in). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafing_(gaming)) for more info.

"Strafe your shot" would be shooting while moving side to side like this, since only moving sidewards (as opposed to backwards) would cause you to be aiming at a different place every time you shot.